# Want to download the file which was recently uploaded by user in django?

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
import os
# Create your models here.
class Fileupload(models.Model):
    file=models.FileField( upload_to='media')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

This is my Views.py

```
from msilib.schema import File
from urllib import response
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from .models import Fileupload
from .encryptfile import encrypt

# import required module
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Django file encrytion process from https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-files/
# Import mimetypes module
import mimetypes
# def index(request):
#     return render(request, 'index.html')

def base(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file2 =request.FILES["file"]
        # name = request.FILES["file"].name
        # path = "media/"+name
        document = Fileupload.objects.create(file=file2)
        document.save()
        fname = Fileupload.filename(document)
        global path1 
        path1 ="media/"+fname
        # print(fname)

        #encrypting the uploaded file which is file2
        # opening the key
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        with open("thekey.key","wb") as thekey:
            thekey.write(key)
        
        # opening the original file to encrypt
        with open(path1, 'rb') as file:
            original = file2.read()
            
        # encrypting the file
        encrypted = Fernet(key).encrypt(original)

        # opening the file in write mode and
        # writing the encrypted data
        with open(path1, 'wb') as encrypted_file:
            encrypted_file.write(encrypted)
        
        
        return render(request,'download.html')
    else:

        return render(request, 'base.html')

def download(request):
    # Define Django project base directory
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    # Define text file name
    # filename = Fileupload.filename()
    # Define the full file path
    filepath = BASE_DIR + '/media/' + filename
    # Open the file for reading content
    path1 = open(filepath, 'r')
    # Set the mime type
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
    # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
    response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
    # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    # Return the response value
    return render(request, response,'base.html')
    

def decrypt(request):
      
    return render(request, 'decrypt.html')
    # return HttpResponse("This is about page")

# def encrypt(request):
#     return render(request, 'encrypt.html')
#     # return HttpResponse("This is contact page")
 
# def address(request):
#     return render(request, 'address.html')
#     # return HttpResponse("This is address page")
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Home import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
import django.conf.urls as url 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('download',views.download,name='download'),
    path('decrypt',views.decrypt,name='decrypt'),
    path('',views.base,name='base'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
          {% comment %} <form action="/action_page.php" > {% endcomment %}
            <label for="file" class="u-btn u-button-style u-palette-2-base u-btn-1">Select a 
             file:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Encrypt" class="u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u- 
             hover-palette-1-light-1 u-palette-2-light-2 u-radius-6 u-btn-2">
          </form>
```

download.html

```
  <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-image u-shading u-section-1" 
      src="static/img/bghack.jpg" data-image-width="7395" data-image-height="4933" id="sec- 
         f710">
        <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
          <h1 class="u-text u-text-default u-title u-text-1">ENCRYPTION OF FILES</h1>
          <p class="u-large-text u-text u-text-default u-text-variant u-text-2">The file has 
       been encrypted. Download the file by clicking the button below.</p>
          {% if url %}
          <div class = "download">
          <a  href="{{ url }}" type="button" download class="u-btn u-button-style u-palette-2- 
        base u-btn-1">Download the file</a>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
          
        </div>
      </section>
```

Having problem with downloading the file saved to media by user.
And also tell how to delete the file after the file has been download.
I want to create encryption and dercrytion website

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do this:

```
def download(request, filename=''):
    if filename != '':
        # Define Django project base directory
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        # Define the full file path
        filepath = BASE_DIR + '/media/' + filename
        # Open the file for reading content
        path = open(filepath, 'rb')
        # Set the mime type
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
        # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
        response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
        # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        # Return the response value
        return response
    else:
        # Load the template
        return render(request, 'file.html')
```

in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'download' filename='test.txt' %}">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but how would i know what is the filename.